# How to get the plugins in Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

I've used to get all the plugins using IPluginRegistry when it is deprecated and now in the new version, some of its methods implementations are removed like getPluginRegistry.

```
IPluginRegistry pReg = Platform.getPluginRegistry();
IPluginDescriptor[] plugins = pReg.getPluginDescriptors();
IPluginPrerequisite[] pPrereqs = plugins[i].getPluginPrerequisites();
```

Is there any alternative for above code ?

Also i can't able to get the Plugin from plugin-id like below in eclipse 4.3, The getPlugin(plugin_id) method is deprecated and removed their implementation in new version. Is there any alternative for below code too ?

```
Plugin plugin = Platform.getPlugin(pluginId);
boolean bool = plugin instanceOf MyCustomPlugin;
```

MyCustomPlugin.java

```
public abstract MYCustomPlugin extends AbstractUIPlugin{
}
```

If i use the bundle like below, i was able to get only package name without plugin name like `com.plugins.pluginPack` instead of `com.plugins.pluginPack.MyCustomPlugin`. I need complete plugin instead of just the package name.

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId);
```

I appreciate if someone helps me out !!
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this? It is harder to answer when we don't know exactly what data you want.

Comment: @greg-449 I need the pluginPrerequisites for my code. I appreciate if you can help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because IPluginDescriptor is no more supporting so, for "plugin descriptor" uniqueIdentifier we can use bundle

```
Myplugin plugin;  //this Myplugin extending Plugin abstract class

IPluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor = plugin.getDescriptor();
String uniqueIdentifier = pluginDescriptor.getUniqueIdentifier();
```

**Alternative(below)

```
String uniqueIdentifier = plugin.getBundle().getSymbolicName()
```

For plugin object, you can find an alternative using bundle and org.osgi.framework.Constants

```
Plugin plugin = Platform.getPlugin(pluginId);
```

**Alternative(below)

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId);
String activator = (String)bundle.getHeaders().get(Constants.BUNDLE_ACTIVATOR);
Object activatorInstance = bundle.loadClass(activator).newInstance();
Plugin plugin = (Plugin) activatorInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the platform state to get a list of installed bundle descrptions:

```java
State state = Platform.getPlatformAdmin().getState();
BundleDescription [] bundles = state.getBundles();
```

The `BundleDescription` has methods such as `getRequiredBundles` that return a list of the bundle's requirements.

```java
BundleSpecification [] specs = desc.getRequiredBundles();
```

You can no longer get the `Plugin` for a plugin, you can get the `Bundle` for a plugin using:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

Since there is only ever one instance of a plugin's class you can use a static in the class to save that instance - `ResourcesPlugin` does this for example:

```java
public final class ResourcesPlugin extends Plugin {
  private static ResourcesPlugin plugin;

  public ResourcesPlugin() {
    plugin = this;
  }

  public static ResourcesPlugin getPlugin() {
    return plugin;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 . But i have one more issue, `Plugin pugin  = Platform.getPlugin(pluginId)` is not working anymore and can you help me get an alternative process to get `'Plugin'` from `'pluginId'` please

Comment: That simply is no longer available. Again you need to explain what you need it for. You can get the `Bundle` which has some of the information - added to answer.

Comment: @greg449 I need to check if the plugin is an instance of MyCustomPlugin

Comment: There is only ever one instance of a plugin class so you can just save the instance in the plugin activator - see example of `ResourcesPlugin` I can't find any other way to access details of the activator

Comment: so, can you tell me how can i get all the plugins from the bundle because bundle doesn't have the Plugin name and it contains only plugin package name `com.myplugin.customPlugin` and not the plugin name `ResourcesPlugin`!!

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this anymore. You are going to have to do whatever it is you want to do a different way.